# Write byte array to storage file in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm using Visual studio 2012, c#, silverlight, windows phone 8 app.

We get our data from a webservice, and through the webservice we get a picture that is an base64 string.

I convert it to a byte array, and now I want to save it so the Storage of the windows phone, using a memory stream? I don't know if it is the right approach. I don't want to save it to isolated storage, just the local folder because I want to show the picture after a person tapped on the link.

this is what I have so far.

```
 byte[] ImageArray;
 var image = Attachmentlist.Attachment.ToString();
 imagename = Attachmentlist.FileName.ToString();
 ImageArray = Convert.FromBase64String(image.ToString());

 StorageFolder myfolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
 await myfolder.CreateFileAsync(imagename.ToString());
 StorageFile myfile = await myfolder.GetFileAsync(imagename.ToString());


 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
```

so after I have initialized the memory stream how do I take the byte array and write it to the storage file, and after that retrieve it again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To write file to disc try this code:

```
StorageFile sampleFile = await myfolder.CreateFileAsync(imagename.ToString(), 
   CreateCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(sampleFile, ImageArray);
```

Memory stream creates stream that writes in memory so it is not applicable to this problem.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, correct me if i am wrong, but isn't FileIO a visual basic namespace? and if so  what is the visual studio version of FileIO - google isnt much help so far

Comment: @Arrie check this out: [doucmentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.writebytesasync), Its Windows 8 specific class.

Comment: @Arrie how did you make it work for you? I'm also doing Windows Phone 8 but FileIO doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @NiiLaryea i re-did mine, so this is kindof an old answer. and it is to much code to put here? so where can i show you my code that i used?

Comment: @Arrie can you please check my profile and send me an email? Thanks.

Comment: @NiiLaryea uhmm i have no idea how to do that? :)

Comment: @Arrie I mean you should just click on my username to go to my profile and send me an email. My email address is on my profile.

Comment: @NiiLaryea im blind then haha, i really cant see an email address, email me if you can see mine cause i have no idea where to look for it

Comment: @Arrie I'm sorry I can see mine so I thought you would see it too :). I can't see yours either. My email address is boyealexzoe at gmail dot com

Comment: `CreationCollisionOption` - typo

Answer (score 6):

```
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile imageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Sample.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (IOutputStream outputStream = fileStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {
                using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                {
                    dataWriter.WriteBytes(imageBuffer);
                    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                    dataWriter.DetachStream();

                }
                //await outputStream.FlushAsync();
            }
            //await fileStream.FlushAsync();
        }
```